# How do I change my profile / avatar picture on my account for Starcraft II?

Tags: starcraft-2

My avatar picture defaulted to, I think it's the photo of the guy from the SCV unit.  How do I change this to something else?  I can't seem to find an option for this anywhere.

Comment: See also: [How to unlock profile icons](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4215/how-to-unlock-the-various-profile-icons-in-starcraft-2)

Comment: do you change the picture on any web browser when surfing your account or within the game and on-line? I am unable to do it... and I have unlocked some profile phots already...

Comment: You change it within the game.  Look at the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Click on your photo in the upper-right to go to your profile.  Then, click on the Rewards menu item, and then Portraits.  You can see all of your choices there.  You unlock more choices through achievements.

You cannot upload any photo you want.

Comment: After the 3.7 (or whatever) update this process seems different and the described algorithm is no longer valid. I haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Comment: This answer is outdated. See the answer below about the Collections tab.

Answer (score 5):

The old Rewards section in the profile dialog has been replaced with a new **Collections** tab in the main menu. The **Portraits** sub-tab allows you to select any portrait you own, which you can activate by pressing the **Equip** button.

[image: screenshot of StarCraft 2 showing the "Portraits" sub-tab under the "Collection" tab in the menu]

Answer (score 4):

The quickest way I know is to right click on your portrait in the top right corner and choose "Change portrait".