# How do you unlock the various profile icons?

Tags: starcraft-2

How do you unlock the various profile icons in Starcraft 2?

Is it purely going through campaigns?  Unlocking certain achievements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hovering over each of the icons will tell you what you need to do to get it. Each is an achievement of some sort.

Some are from the campaigns, some are from multiplayer... Look at the list of profile icons, and you get the achievement it needs.

Comment: see also: [How do I change my profile / avatar picture?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4091/how-do-i-change-my-avatar-picture-on-my-account-for-starcraft-ii)